# External javascript not loading with PhantomJS and selenium webdriver on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, python, macos, selenium, phantomjs

I have a python script that uses PhantomJS with selenium webdriver to retrieve a page which works perfectly on Ubuntu, while on Mac OS X  it does not get some javascript library correctly.

This is more evident on a stackoverflow webpage which has a dedicated message for it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
browser.save_screenshot("so.png")
```

Ubuntu with PhantomJS 1.9.8:

[image: PhantomJS on Ubuntu]

Mac OS X with PhantomJS 2.0:

[image: PhantomJS on Mac OS X]

The two tests are performed on the same network and both the machines can open the webpage correctly when using a classical browser.

Comment: Try to run it with `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` as a commandline option.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It works, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. The question is pretty similar, but it would be interesting to understand why on Ubuntu it works and on Mac OS X it fails.

Comment: PhantomJS probably fails to use the certificate store of OSX for some reason.